# How to call JavaScript function inside the Telerik().Grid button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to call the Ajax function inside the Telerik().Grid.

This is my Telerik().Grid

```
 @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("SiteGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.PKComID).Width(50);
             columns.Bound(o => o.CompanyName).Width(50);    
//In here I want to add a button and call the Ajax function when click the button   
        })    

          .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(15).Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric).Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
                 .Sortable()
    )
```

This is my Java script function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getCompanyDetails(companyID) {

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '@Url.Action("CompanybyID", "Search")',
            data: ({ ComID: companyID }),
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('#companyDetails').html(data);


            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });

    }
  </script>
```

How can I call the `getCompanyDetails()` function in side the grid view?

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("SiteGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.PKComID).Width(50);
            columns.Bound(o => o.CompanyName).Width(50);      
        })    
           .ClientEvents(events => events.OnComplete("getCompanyDetails"))
          .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(15).Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric).Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
                 .Sortable()
    )
```

official example:  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/customcolumncommand